# How this select statement executes?

Tags: go, channel

```golang
incoming := make(chan int)
done := make(chan struct{})

...
close(done)
...

select {
    case incoming <- order:
        // logic
    case <-done:
        return 
    }
```

Let's say you close the done channel before the select statement:

1.The case <-done will be selected.

2.Is this because when close(done) executes, the done channel will be in a state, in which the select statement will consider the "case <-done" a match over the writing case "incoming <- order"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `select` statement blocks until one or more of the [communication operations](https://go.dev/ref/spec#CommCase) in its `cases` can *proceed*. As soon as one or more communication operations can proceed `select` will *randomly* choose one of them.

A *receive* operation on a closed `channel` can *proceed* immediately.

---

[Select Statement](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:
>
> 1. For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of
>    receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions
>    of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order,
>    upon entering the "select" statement. The result is a set of
>    channels to receive from or send to, and the corresponding values
>    to send. Any side effects in that evaluation will occur
>    irrespective of which (if any) communication operation is selected
>    to proceed. Expressions on the left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a > short variable declaration or assignment are not yet evaluated.
> 2. **If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one
>    that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.**
>    Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If
>    there is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at
>    least one of the communications can proceed.
> 3. Unless the selected case is the default case, the respective
>    communication operation is executed.
> 4. If the selected case is a RecvStmt with a short variable
>    declaration or an assignment, the left-hand side expressions are
>    evaluated and the received value (or values) are assigned.
> 5. The statement list of the selected case is executed.

[Receive operator](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Receive_operator):

> A receive operation on a closed channel **can always proceed
> immediately**, yielding the element type's zero value after any
> previously sent values have been received.